# How to improve this email regex?

Tags: python, regex, email-validation

I am trying to match email addresses in Python using regex with this pattern:

```
"\w{1,}@\w{1,}.\w{1,}"
```

However sometimes there are email addresses that look like `firstname.lastname@lol.omg.hahaha.museum` which my pattern will miss.

Is there a way to adjust this regex so it will include an arbitrary number of chained ".word" type patterns?

Comment: Yeah - `'@' in string`. This is the best you can do.

Comment: Use `[\w.]` instead of `\w`.

Comment: @user51819 - Vaultah actually makes a valid point; it is _very_ difficult to have a valid regular expression for an email (just because there are many different formats that a valid email address can take). Many applications use a simple check for the at-symbol within the string (and something after the at-symbol)

Comment: BTW, instead of `{1,}` you should use `+`.

Comment: You can't just check for @ in string because then you'd be matching on non-email addresses like "@randomword" or "I'll meet you @7" or "@someone: hi!" or "gibberish@gibberish more gibberish"

Comment: Are you trying to validate an entered email address, or search for email addresses in text?

Comment: @Barmar what is "+"?

Comment: @Barmar Scrape email addresses from text

Comment: `+` is like `*`, but it matches 1 or more instead of 0 or more. Just like `{1,}` does.

Comment: "gibberish@gibberish" is a valid email address (believe it or not!)

Comment: @ChrisForrence Even without a ".word" suffix?!

Comment: Theoretically you can use a top-level domain for email. The owner of `.com` could create addresses like `owner@com`. Practically, no one does this, and there are probably millions of address validators that won't allow it.

Comment: More likely, `gibberish` and `nonsense` could be two subdomains or hosts within the same domain, and mail between the two can drop the common suffix. Similar to (but implemented separately from?) DNS search domains.

Comment: I'd use `\s+(.*?@.*?\..*?)\s+`.

Comment: From [html5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#valid-e-mail-address) `^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
[\w.-]+@[\w-][\w.-]+\w   //replaced {1,} with its equivalent.. "+"
```

Comment: @Barmar yes I did.. but I dont see user asking for it?

Comment: Won't this incorrectly pick up periods that are at the ends of sentences? For example "my email is myname@somewhere.com."

Comment: I am just trying to understand the structure. What does "[\w.-]" by itself mean? a-zA-Z0-9_ character or period or hiphen?

Comment: @user51819 it means match any of the characters in the set `[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]`

Comment: So that last piece forces the last character to be a-zA-Z0-9_, cool! This regex was informative, thanks

Comment: @user51819 `\w` has the same meaning inside brackets as it does outside brackets.

Comment: @Barnar Do you mean something like [\w.-]+@[\w-][\w.-]+\w

Comment: @karthikmanchala Is there a way to negate something? Like if you want to say "I don't want this to be a \w"

Comment: @user51819 you can use negated set `[^ ]` i.e .. in this case `[^\w]`

Comment: What about "(?<!\w)"?

Comment: @user51819 it means `negative lookbehind` and it matches positions where previous character is not `\w`..

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to match email addresses with regex. You'll have to use a more complicated state machine to check whether the address correctly matches RFC 2822.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/validate_email is one such library you can check out.

Comment: According to his comment, he's not doing validation, he's scraping.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{2,4}
```

Comment: That will miss addresses that I use. But I'm okay with that.

Comment: Any reason you don't use `\w` instead of `a-zA-Z0-9_`, like his original regexp does?

Comment: Can you do \w+ instead of [a-zA-Z0-9._-]+?

Comment: @user51819 `\w` is short for letters, numbers, and underscore. It doesn't include dot or dash. That's why your original regexp doesn't work.

Comment: I've found that `\w` sometimes includes some weird chars that would not be valid in an email address. I suppose it depends on what language you are using.